# Magmi installation localhost

Tags: importexport, magmi

I am trying to build an ecommerce site and I'm stuck on how to import bulk products on magmi, after searching through the web i have  not found a clear walk-through on how to setup magmi and use it to import products to my magento store, I hope someone here can lead me the way, thank you in advance

Comment: @marius I dont see why this question is closed as I have seen a lot of Magmi questions answered on the Magento stackexchange ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would actually do it, may be there is a better more intuitive way, here it goes:

- Get the latest stable version from Github from this link
  [dweeves/magmi-git](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git) , either by cloning it using Git or
  downloading the zip file from the right column.

  [image]
- Head to your Magento directory, and put it there, in my case it will
  be in:

  > /var/www/magento/magmi-git
- Make sure the permissions on that directory allows for creating new
  files and directories.
- In your browser, go to your magento, and add to that the URL to the
  web interface for Magmi; which is:

  > http://www.magento.local/magmi-git/magmi/web/magmi.php
- You will be looking at the page where Magmi loads different profiles for different scenarios like: Product Import, Product Stock Update, Images import, etc.

[image]

- You will need to go under "Configure current profile" which will be called "Default" at the time you install it, and choose (Copy selected profile to) option to some other name, then press on "copy profile and switch"
- Now you should be on the same page, but a different profile, where
  you setup your global parameters, like host, username, password,
  magento path. One you save, you will find your configuration saved in
  a file under:

  > /var/www/mage/magmi-git/magmi/conf
- Now I can say that you are good to start importing, just take a note that the CSV base directory in your profile should be known to you since this is where you will be placing the CSVs to import.
- Structure of files can be found right here [enter link description here](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Import_new_products)
- And I hope this helps.